# Write Number as string csv python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a csv file from json data. During that, i want to write '001023472' but its writing as '1023472'. I have searched a lot. But dint find an answer.

The value is of type string before writing. The problem is during writing it into the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the type to str like str(001023472)

Comment: You can use formatting

Comment: Look at the chapter on Strings in the Python manual. Much of it is dedicated to formatting output. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html

Comment: @AvinashGarg that is a SyntaxError in Python 3 (leading 0s are prohibited in numeric literals), and in Python 2 it will convert the number to octal (would be a SyntaxError if there were an 8 or 9).

Comment: @AvinashGarg plus it doesn't seem like the OP actually has a literal but something from a JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to string with formatting operator; in your case: `"%09d" % number`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`format` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) or [`format` string method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

```
>>> format(1023472, '09')
'001023472'
>>> '{:09}'.format(1023472)
'001023472'
```

If your "number" is actually a string, you can also just left-pad it with `'0'`'s:

```
>>> format('1023472', '>09')
'001023472'
```

The Python docs generally eschew `%` formatting, saying it may go away in the future and is also more finnicky; for new code there is no real reason to use it, especially in 2.7+.

Comment: still i get the value as '1023472' in my csv file. i want '001023472'

Comment: Is it a string from your CSV? You could cast it to int then use the format methods, or just pad the string with 0's.

Comment: i'm writing in a csv file from json data. one of my json value is '001023472' which i want to write into one of columns in csv file. But there seems to be a problem while writing. the value is of type string but when i write it to csv it is changed as int.

Comment: What are you writing your CSV with? I don't think the standard library `csv` package converts strings to ints. I'm still a bit confused as to the `type()` of your "json value".